# Skip & Top parameters do not pass to the backend

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

Submitting the request below from to my Server having put a break-point at the beginning of my GET_ENTITYSET method (just pay attention to the skip/top params at the beginning)

```
GET AgreementsSet?$skip=0&$top=10&$filter=(AgrStatid%20eq%20%27002%27%20or%20AgrStatid%20eq%20%27003%27)%20and%20(StartDate%20ge%20datetime%272014-01-01T00%3a00%3a00%27%20or%20StartDate%20le%20datetime%272020-09-28T00%3a00%3a00%27)%20and%20(LastActDate%20ge%20datetime%272014-01-01T00%3a00%3a00%27%20or%20LastActDate%20le%20datetime%272020-09-28T00%3a00%3a00%27)
```

At the beginning of the method both IS_PAGING-TOP and IS_PAGING-SKIP are 0 (io_tech_request_context->get_top( )/get_skip( ) bring back the same result). Trying the exact request by copy/paste (just removed the GET and concatenated with my initial path) using Gateway Client and IS_PAGING-TOP is 10 as expected.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Greg

Comment: Took one of my own OData's URLs, entered it into my browser's URL field, and copy-pasted the exact `$skip=0&$top=10` section from your post to the end of it. Works perfectly, when arriving in the `/iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~get_entityset` method, the debugger shows that `IS_PAGING-TOP` is `10`. Only differences I noted are that my URL includes an additional `?sap-client=100` as a first parameter, and that I didn't include the subsequent `$filter` condition.

Comment: yes, try to debug piece by piece, remove the filter and check again. maybe your filter string is corrupted